# Version of microsoft which support vba userform

Tags: vba, excel

Hi im doing a project about excel vba userform and I need to know if all version of microsoft excel(eg earlier or 2000, 2002, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2013 etc) support my userform. May I know which version of microsoft start using userform? The functions in my userfrom include advanced filter, photo control, print preview, login interface.
Thanks first for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The userform are present at least from Excel95 onwards.

You might run into trouble if you use other then the default form controls.

I had once trouble with the progressbar.